# How to highlight parent li text only on :hover?

Tags: css, xhtml

How to highlight Article only on mouse over? current when i hover on Article it highlights all child item also. Is it possible to highlight **Articles** only

see example here http://jsbin.com/ubunu/2

```
<style>
  li:hover {background:red}
li li:hover {background:yellow}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="hello">Hello World</p>
  <ul>
<li>Weblog</li>
<li>Articles
   <ul>
   <li>How to Beat the Red Sox</li>
   <li>Pitching Past the 7th Inning
      <ul>
      <li>Part I</li>
      <li>Part II</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>Eighty-Five Years Isn't All That Long, Really</li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li>About</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sorry, Bostonian here. You lost me when you mentioned beating the Red Sox.

Comment: @Robusto - What do you mean???

Comment: gear-solid: Just kidding you. But we in Red Sox Nation take winning and losing very seriously.

Comment: @Robusto OH!. I just copied this code from a site to just to give a example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to only highlight "Article" when the mouse is over the word, then you'll need to edit the HTML to add some `<span>` tags or something similar around each word:

```
<style>
    li span:hover {background:red}
    li li span:hover {background:yellow}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <p id="hello">Hello World</p>
    <ul>
        <li><span>Weblog</span></li>
        <li><span>Articles</span>
        <ul>
        ...etc
```

EDIT: this looks like a menu - in which case you'll be using links, so you can target those instead of using spans.

Answer (score 3):

You'll likely need to mess with some of the positioning on different browsers, but you can add the following to your styles:

```
li:hover ul { background: white; }
li:hover ul li:hover { background: yellow; }
```

Replace "white" with whatever hex, rgb, or color value you need.

Comment: +1 yes good idea. but in that ul,li li:hover will show till if my moues is on child item inside ul. but i think this is the last possible way in css.

Comment: NO I mean i want to highlight only one item at a time.